# Why is regex failing on already-escaped quotes?

Tags: php, regex

I am using the following regex:

```
$regex = "/Built upon the <a href=\"[^>]+banshee-php\\.org/\">[a-z]+<\/a>(?:v([\\d.]+))?\\;version:\\1/U";
```

And i'm running it against the markup of a typical webpage using `preg_match` but its dying at a quotation mark.

> preg_match(): Unknown modifier '"'

Since all of the quotes are already escaped, I'm not sure why its not running.

Comment: You forgot to escape the `/` after `.org`.

Comment: Avoid escaping altogether and use: `'~Built upon the <a href="[^>]+banshee-php\.org/">[a-z]+</a>(?:v([\d.]+))?\\;version:\1~U'`

Comment: Is `[\\d.]` intentional?

Comment: After escaping the `/` after `.org` as per Tim's suggestion, i still ran into the failure. then I applied @anubhava 's suggestion and it worked. thanks. if you'd like, go ahead and make an answer, and I'll upvote it and resolve the question.

Comment: @Kristian: That's great, I provided that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid all the escaping by choosing a different `regex delimiter` and using single quotes around your string like this:

```
$re='~Built upon the <a href="[^>]+banshee-php\.org/">[a-z]+</a>(?:v([\d.]+))?\\;version:\1~U';
```